# How to get Espresso to run for API21 with multidexed apk?

Tags: android, android-espresso, dagger, android-multidex

I have an large app that is multidexed running API 21, has Dagger 1.2 and when I add in Espresso with Jake Wharton's ActivityRule it can't install the application on either an emulator or a physical phone.  I get the following dialog box.

> Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
>   In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>   Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

**I hit OK** and the Test framework quits unexpectedly with

```
Testing started at 4:23 PM ...
```

Target device: genymotion-google_nexus_4___5_0_0___api_21___768x1280-192.168.56.101:5555
Installing APK: C:\AAAAAOtto\Otto\Otto\app\build\outputs\apk\app-developercode-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp
Installing com.example.myapp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.myapp
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

**Here's** my gradle build with the debug version at min and max at api 21 to overtly not bring any pre 5.0 issues in with Espresso.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.5"
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21   
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"   

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.myapp'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1430
    versionName "1.4.30"
    multiDexEnabled = true
```

//        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
   //        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
productFlavors {
    developercode {
        minSdkVersion 21
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp'

        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1430
        versionName '1.4.30'
    }
    integrationcode {
        minSdkVersion 16
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp'

        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1430
        versionName '1.4.30'
    }
    eridesharecode {
        minSdkVersion 16
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp'
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1430
        versionName '1.4.30'
    }
}
dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "2g" }
compileOptions {
    encoding "UTF-8"
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.6'
compile 'com.tundem.aboutlibraries:library:4.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.1.0'
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.joanzapata.mapper:simple-mapper:1.0.10'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

// Espresso

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
//            {
//        exclude group: 'javax.inject'}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'}

//    // Jacoco config
//    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
//
//    jacoco {
//        // Use this version for upper ones are broken (with Gradle)
//        // https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/288
//        toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
//    }
//
//// Edit covered scope if needed
//// For my part I like having the coverage of both application and tests
//    def coverageSourceDirs = [
//            '../app/src'
//    ]
//
//    task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test") {
//        group = "Reporting"
//
//        description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"
//
//        classDirectories = fileTree(
//                dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes',
//                excludes: ['**/R.class',
//                           '**/R$*.class',
//                           '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
//                           '**/BuildConfig.*',
//                           '**/Manifest*.*']
//        )
//
//        additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
//        sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
//        executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testUnitTestDebug.exec')
//
//        reports {
//            xml.enabled = true
//            html.enabled = true
//        }
//
//    }
////end Jacoco config

}
```

P.S.  I tried with and without the Jacoco fix above, no difference.

**Here's** important parts of my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

package="com.example.myapp">

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.animator"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />


<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!-- The following four permissions -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcherx"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BaseTheme1"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_v2_api_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        ...
     />

</application>

</manifest>
```

**For** the app I have the following Android Studio configuration set

android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

**The** extended application class has

```
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: If you use only parts of the Play Services instead of the whole thing ( `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`) as per https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup then you might not even need Multidex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already know that will work.  I want to know what to do when the app is Multidexed. Best.

Comment: I agree, this is a valid question too.

Comment: I've done that, see beginning of question, i.e.  'can't install the application on either an emulator or a physical phone.'

Comment: Did you fix your issue ?